# Get the Item id when creating dynamic pages on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been searching for several days now trying to find how to retrieve the item id of a select item from a mySQL database on a wordpress website.

I have a database of several hundreds of recipes. They are all displayed in a list on a certain page. I then want to be able to click on one of the recipes in the link and be sent to a unique `recipe.php` page.

The list of all recipes is on `main-page.php`. On this page, I have created the following:

```
                echo '<td class="recipe"><a href=recipe?id='.$id.'><div class="recipe-container"><img src="'.$img.'" id="recipe-image"/>';
                echo '<div class=recipe_name>'.$nam.'</a></div>';
```

As you can see, clicking on a recipe with the id of `4` would send you to `www.example.com/recipe?id=4`.

My question is, how do I tell the code to recognize that we are on the page for recipe #4, so that I can display its unique details? In particular, what do I write in `recipe.php` so that I can display the unique content for the selected recipe?

Answer (score 1):

create an onload() event on the `recipe.php`, then check for $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to retrieve `id` value and retrieve data from database based on the value

Comment: Is this something like AJAX then? I'm a little confused. `onload()` You are referring too is JS is it not? Is that necessary or can I not just call `$_SERVER['id']`

Comment: @McLean25 you can call `$_SERVER['id']` at any function within the page with query string, no only `onload()`, `onload()` is an event for all control in a page when they load to page, for page `onload()`, put on html body.

Answer (score 0):

Found the awnser. All I had to do was:

`$id = $_GET['id']`

Had no idea it would be that easy.